# How to force min value only positive numbers including 0 and avoid validors.required fire on 0 value

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I realized on Angular version 12.2.16 if I include on my formControl

```
[Validators.min(0), Validators.required]
```

The validors.required is been fired when I introduce 0 as the value of the formControl.

Any idea fellows?

Answer (score 0):

you can possibly do it using custom validator something like this

```
 customValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      return control.value >= 0 ? null : { notMatched: true }
    };
```

}

```
form = this.formBuilder.group({
      key: this.customValidator(),
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but at last I discovered the issue came up because of using a own component instead of input of material